Error occured during the signature verification on Raspberry Pi
I want to set up a smb server at home using my raspberry and I can't get it to download properly, so I tried running sudo apt-get update but following error occured:
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/InRelease  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bookworm_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Splitting of clearsigned file /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bookworm_InRelease failed as it doesn't contain all expected parts
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

thanks for the help in advance

Welcome, first use sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt update

@GAD3R When i do that following error shows up: E: Splitting of clearsigned file /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bookworm_InRelease failed as it doesn't contain all expected parts E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Could you please edit your question to make it clear what OS you have installed, and add the contents of the file /etc/apt/sources.list on your RPi??
